# Blurry Library Android not effecting

Tags: android, blur, effect

I know this question was already asked but I tried all others answer I found but it's still not working
for me.

I'm trying to blur a layout with the [Blurry Library](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry). Here is my code :

```
private void blur() {
        final Activity activity = this;

        blurBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Blurry.with(activity)
                        .radius(15)
                        .sampling(8)
                        .color(getResources().getColor(R.color.shadow))
                        .async()
                        .onto(relBlur);
            }
        });
    }
```

And my gradle app :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    
    defaultConfig {
        
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29

        renderscriptTargetApi 29
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

-----------

implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:3.0.0'
```

My `RelativeLayout` is not blurred after the Click

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please provide what is your problem.

Comment: it just doesn't work when I click the layout is not blurred